# Can you have a "strongly" typed DataReader result set?

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

What I'm trying to do is to safe guard my C# data retrieval code from IndexOutOfRangeException when using datareader.GetOrdinal(). This is no problem if my procedures don´t change and they just return just one result set. But if they return multiple result sets then I need to iterate the result sets with .NextResult(). That is no problem.

**But what if somebody changes the procedure to have another select statement so that the order of my C# retrieval code changes and everything blows up?**

But the question is: **Can I check if the result is the result that I want?**

**Here below is the pseudo code for what I like to do.**

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   //The check I would like to be able to do 
   if(reader.Result != "The result with someColumnName")
   {
     //This is not the result Im looking for so I try the next one
     reader.NextResult();
   }
   else //Get the result set I want.. If it blows up now it should..
   {
      if (reader.HasRows)
      {
        //Get all ordinals first. Faster than searching with index.
         int someColumnNameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("someColumnName");
         while (reader.Read())
         {
           var someValue = reader.GetString(someColumnNameOrdinal );
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I know that I could try to GetOrdinal, get exception, catch it and then try the next result, but that is just to damn unclean (and wrong).

Comment: You could call GetSchemaTable but probably this will slow down your code noticeably.

Comment: Year 2014, trying to achieve what an OR/M gives you out of the box... A complete waste of time

Comment: not sure about data reader, but you can bind DataTable to strongly typed model.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer there's a lot of old software that uses this kind of stuff and without rewriting the whole application it is not possible to use anything newer. Perhaps this is such case.

Comment: @t3chb0t With these mappings based on convention over configuration, it's still a waste of time not using an OR/M instead of wasting your time creating a square wheel. I would prefer to "waste" my time learning an OR/M which ensures that I will end implementing a trully successful solution than using my time to understand how to develop an OR/M and end up with an horrible solution

Comment: @matíasFidemraizer Im not starting a new project. I fully know and use e.g Entity Framework in my solutions but this as t3chb02 pointed out this is a older system that is huge! So Im not going to rewrite the whole thing. I´m just trying to move away from Datasets to something more strongly typed. Im trying to move away from datasets/tables, but binding to a model sounds great.

Comment: @Sturla If you're moving from X to Y, I don't see why you can't use an OR/M

Answer (score 0):

Using OR/M is a good practice, but there are exceptions, of course. For example, you may be forced to query SQL server which does not support stored procs (SQL Server Compact etc.). To increase performance you may opt to using SqlDataReader. To ensure that your field names are always correct (correspond to your entity class fields) you may use the following practice - instead of hard-coding field names use this code instead:

```
GetPropertyName((YourEntityClass c) => c.YourField)
```

Where *GetPropertyName* function contains the following code (generics are used):

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T, TReturn>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, TReturn>> expression)
{
    System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression body = (System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

*YourEntityClass* is a class name for your table in Entity Framework, *YourField* is a field name in this table. In this case you have performance of SqlDataReader and safety of Entity Framework in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each of the result sets has a uniquely named first column, for the following line in your pseudo code example:

```
if(reader.Result != "The result with someColumnName")
```

you could use the [SqlDataReader.GetName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname.aspx) function to check the name of the first column. For example:

```
if(reader.GetName(0) != "ExpectedColumnName")
```